# How to create a DataFrame using resampling method?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns:

```
Date,Price,Dividends
2021-03-10 00:00:00-05:00,22.80156707763672,0.311
2021-06-09 00:00:00-04:00,23.896337509155273,0.316
2021-09-09 00:00:00-04:00,25.87319564819336,0.316
2021-12-09 00:00:00-05:00,25.81643295288086,0.327
2022-03-10 00:00:00-05:00,29.82132339477539,0.327
2022-06-09 00:00:00-04:00,27.844614028930664,0.339
2022-09-08 00:00:00-04:00,26.46453857421875,0.339
2022-12-08 00:00:00-05:00,26.134775161743164,0.351
2023-03-09 00:00:00-05:00,25.100820541381836,0.351
2023-06-08 00:00:00-04:00,24.20918846130371,0.364
2023-09-07 00:00:00-04:00,22.228063583374023,0.364
2023-12-08 00:00:00-05:00,24.66359519958496,0.376
2024-03-08 00:00:00-05:00,23.360000610351562,0.376
```

I want to group the DataFrame by year using `df.resample` method.

I am tried two approaches:

```
yearly_price_avg = df.resample("Y", on="Date")["Price"].mean()
```

and

```
yearly_price_avg = df.resample("Y", on="Date").agg({"Price":"mean"})
yearly_price_avg.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The first method return `Series` object, which I do not understand how to convert into a DataFrame. The second gives me the DataFrame I need. I looked at official pandas documents, but did not get it - why the difference? Can anyone explain me the difference?

What I am trying to achieve is to `resample` (i.e. group) the DF by year; then calculate mean of "Price" and sum of "Dividends"; finally, create a new column "Dividend"/"Price".

Comment: can you provide desired output of your input as text table?

Comment: In the first code you slice a series. You could use `df.resample("Y", on="Date")[["Price"]].mean()`
or `to_frame()`

Comment: For your final result `df.resample("Y", on="Date").agg({"Price":"mean","Dividends":"sum"}).eval("Dividends/Price")`